# Simple way to nest template-driven forms Angular

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, typescript, jhipster

I've been going through similar questions in both StackOverflow and GitHub, but all approaches to a solution are attached to a particular case and that's really not my goal as I have several applications with different case-scenarios and ideally I would like to have transferrable code (isn't that ultimate goal of Software Development anyway?)

I have a big form with deep nesting (4 levels)

Now, I would much rather avoid learning all about ReactiveForms at this point, but I just can't find a simple way to nest template-driven either

Let's say I have a form like:

```
<form class="container-fluid" name="editForm" #editForm="ngForm">
```

Now I have a number of fields, with two-way bindings

And now I need to introduce my first level of nesting, I declare the component like this:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'jhi-survey-data',
    templateUrl: 'surveyData.template.html',
})
```

Export the class and bring inputs to the controller code:

```
export class SurveyDataFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() formDTO: FormDTO;
    @Input('surveyDataDTO') surveyDataDTO: any;
    @Input('i') i: number;
```

And I attach it to the DOM like:

```
<div *ngFor="let surveyDataDTO of formDTO.surveyDataDTOs; let i=index;">
            <jhi-survey-data
                [formDTO]="formDTO"
                [surveyDataDTO]="surveyDataDTO"
                [i]="i">
            </jhi-survey-data>
            </br></br>
        </div>
```

The issue here is that when I try to save changes, they will save fine for any changes on the top component, but not at all on the second.

I've tried by a shared service, accessing the component from there when saving and trying to pick up data, but it comes back as undefined, I guess the "connection" (lacking a better way to describe it) to the objects in the component is closed to any access outside the main component

I've tried grouping the `<jhi-survey_data>` in a `ngModelGroup` and to the exact same result

I guess the question here is if there is actually a simple way to nest template-driven forms or is this going to be a source of pain until Angular team decides if it's enough of us not willing to learn ReactiveForms?

I really don't want to use workarounds or boilerplate code